# Kotlin setOnClickListener using method reference not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, method-reference

I tried to use method reference the same way as in Java:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this::clickListener);
```

Using Kotlin:

```
button.setOnClickListener {this::clickListener}
```

However this doesn't work in Kotlin, the solution is to actually invoke the function withing the labmda expression:

```
button.setOnClickListener {clickListener()}
```

Why Kotlin doesn't accept the method reference in this case? Isn't the same principle as with Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curly braces denote the contents of the lambda expression. Kotlin has already passed an instance of an OnClickListener behind the scenes and is providing the `onClick()` method to you.

If you want to pass a listener you have assigned to a variable, use parentheses:

```
button.setOnClickListener(clickListener)
```

If you want to use a function, it's the same as Java:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this::clickListener)

fun clickListener(v: View) {}
```

Comment: That makes sense. But you propose assigning the listener to a variable, which is not what I want. I want something similar as in Java, just defining a method and just pass the reference to that method with "this::method" as argument to the setOnClickListener.

Comment: @FraK same syntax as Java then. Pass `this::clickListener` in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is basically the same, I was just confused with the lambda expression, and the suppressed parenthesis when using a lambda expression in Kotlin

Answer (score 6):

Although this has already been answered, I'd like to expand the existing answers.

As TheWanderer already mentioned, curly braces here means the body of the lambda. Kotlin supports putting callbacks *outside* regular parenthesis.

This:

```
button.setOnClickListener {clickListener()}
```

Is equal to:

```
button.setOnClickListener({clickListener()})
```

which is equal to:

```java
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener();
    }
});
```

Or (Java 8 only):

```java
button.setOnClickListener(view -> clickListener());
```

**TL;DR:** contents of function arguments are defined with `()`, and lambda bodies are defined with `{}` (just like with regular functions, classes, interfaces, etc.).

Now, first of all, a onClick method callback takes a `view` argument. If you use a standalone function, it needs to have this argument:

```
fun clickListener(view: View) { TODO("Place your listener code here") }
```

This is based on the naming -- if you're implementing `OnClickListener`, just pass `this` as the argument. You already have the listener and function, so you don't need to explicitly define one to pass. However, if you do implement `OnClickListener`, make sure to check the ID before taking action if you have multiple views using it as a listener.

If you are using methods, the next depends on how.

## Using `var` or `val` functions

If your callback is defined as:

```
val listener = {view: View -> 
       TODO()               
    }
```

You can pass it like an argument:

```
button.setOnClickListener(listener)
```

### OnClickListeners

If you have a `var onClickListener: OnClickListener`, the same as with `var`/`val` functions apply.

## Using a function

If you have a `fun clickListener`, you'll have to add lambda to pass it. This is, just like with Java, using `::`. However, you don't need to explicitly declare the scope like in Java. Which means either of these will work:

```
button.setOnClickListener(::clickListener);
button.setOnClickListener(this::clickListener);
// alternatively with a different target, if it's somewhere else.
```

## Further reading

- [Initializing function types - Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in kotlin. Replace curly bracket with parenthesis.

```
btn.setOnClickListener (this::clicklistener)

fun clicklistener(v: View){}
```