# Callback method not being called for googlePayButton

Tags: android, callback, google-pay, android-viewbinding

I have a setOnClickListener() for a Google Pay Button in the OnCreate() in a fragment. I'm using viewbinding to get access to it.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = AddJobScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        paymentsClient =  PaymentsUtil.createPaymentsClient(activity as Activity)
        possiblyShowGooglePayButton()
        binding.include.googlePayButton.setOnClickListener( { requestPayment() })
```

The PayButton is included in the xml of my fragment here:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/googlepay_button"
    android:layout_width="378dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

this is the button itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48sp"
    android:background="@drawable/googlepay_button_no_shadow_background"
    android:paddingTop="2sp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/googlepay_button_content_description">
    <LinearLayout
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:src="@drawable/googlepay_button_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/googlePayButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/googlepay_button_overlay" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the button gets clicked though the callback method requestPayment doesn't get called.
Why is this?

Comment: I've looked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237736/kotlin-setonclicklistener-using-method-reference-not-working and changed `.setOnClickListener( { requestPayment() })` to `.setOnClickListener { (::requestPayment) }` but it made no difference

Comment: I've also tried setting the onClick method directly from the XML but it again didn't react when clicked

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are setting the click listener to an `ImageView` inside of the button. Try setting it to the button element itself:

```
binding.include.googlePayButton.setOnClickListener( { requestPayment() })
```

It'd be useful to give the element a more descriptive name too (eg.: `@+id/googlePayButton`).